# Decrypt a file which is encrypted by openssl in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have a problem of decrypting a text file which is encrypted through command line of openssl as:

```
Key Geanaration:
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1
salt=770AB8C12EF73A4E
key=7EF9E708C05E1767C433E097A66A84AC1971E124E42BDB9D4F0967FF77642AA4
iv =EFFA2B9E2990BC6641E1E5D859D3CF37

File Encryption:
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K 7EF9E708C05E1767C433E097A66A84AC1971E124E42BDB9D4F0967FF77642AA4 -iv EFFA2B9E2990BC6641E1E5D859D3CF37 -in text.txt -out text22.enc
```

But I have a code by which I can not able to decrypt the same as:

```
public void decryptAES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/encrypted.txt");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/decrypted.txt");
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("your_key".getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
    }
```

Comment: We cannot see see that you use the same key.

Comment: No the key in the function is default we can use our own.

Comment: Everybody can use it's own key to decrypt that encrypted file?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement the IV functionality, therefore your first 16 bytes will be different. You do need to use the same key for *symmetric* encryption like AES, and you *should* specify the padding mode, e.g. `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`.